# SQL Server: combine two values in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following union all results

```
ID  Name     Date         Team         Total#1     Total#2
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_1         110          0
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_2         20           0
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_3         170          0
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_1         0            151
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_3         0            98
```

I am looking to combine the results for each team. There are some duplicate team names with different totals and there are some unique teams names with only one total value.

```
ID  Name     Date         Team         Total#1     Total#2
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_1         110          151
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_2         20           0
1   Test_1   4/25/2011    Team_3         170          98
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: combine the results for each `team,id,name,date` combination or for each team? If the latter what should be displayed for `id,name,date` in the event there are differing values in the grouped rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, Name, Date, Team, SUM([Total#1]) [Total#1], SUM([Total#2]) [Total#2]
FROM YourUnionResult
GROUP BY Id, Name, Date, Team
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use aggregate functions and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Date, Team, SUM(Total#1) as Total1, Sum(Total#2) as Total2
FROM Mytable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ID, Name, Date, Team
```

Answer (score 1):

doesn't this work?

```
select id,name,date,team,sum(Total#1) as Total#1,sum(Total#2) as Total#2
from Your table
group by id,name,date,team
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `select... union select...` a subquery, and the "outer" query issues a group by against it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for some reason standard Grouping isn't working for you could do this

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.name, 
       t1.DATE, 
       t1.team, 
       t1.total_1, 
       t2.total_2 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               name, 
               DATE, 
               team, 
               somecomplicatedcalculation total_1 
        FROM   your table) t1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, 
                         name, 
                         DATE, 
                         team, 
                         somecomplicatedcalculation total_2 
                  FROM   your table) t2 
         ON t1.id = t2.id
            and t1.team = t2.team
```

You could also do the same with CTE's

```
WITH t1 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                name, 
                DATE, 
                team, 
                somecomplicatedcalculation total_1 
         FROM   your table), 
     t2 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                name, 
                DATE, 
                team, 
                somecomplicatedcalculation total_2 
         FROM   your table) 
SELECT * 
FROM   t1 
       INNER JOIN t2 
         ON t1.id = t2.id 
            and t1.team = t2.team
```

OR grouping on the union would work to

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       DATE, 
       team, 
       SUM(total_1), 
       SUM(total_2) 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               name, 
               DATE, 
               team, 
               somecomplicatedcalculation total_1, 
               0                          AS total_2 
        FROM   yourtable 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id, 
               name, 
               DATE, 
               team, 
               0                          AS total_1, 
               somecomplicatedcalculation total_2 
        FROM   yourtable) total 
GROUP BY id, 
       name, 
       DATE, 
       team
```